# Accessing verification link in Gmail through Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, testing, watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to Watir and learning it. For learning i have developed a script that does the registration but to complete the registration i need to verify through the mail sent on my GMAIL account. So i have install the ruby GMAIL gem and went through tutorials of github and made sample script below:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
require "gmail"
br = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
br.goto "gmail.com"
gmail = Gmail.new("sample@registration.com", "111111")
gmail.inbox.count(:unread)
gmail.inbox.click(:unread, :from => "noreply@registration.com").label("Confirm Verification")
```

But the script is not working so what could be the error and also that how can i access any mail and click on the verification link.

Comment: I've tried easier scripts and now my registration scripts requires clicking on verification link to complete it. And it goes till the Gmail website but after that script stops and returns **null** value with **GET /shutdown** method

Comment: But that's why the GMAIL gem was created to access GMAIL automatically. So isn't there any way to do it ? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: If you are learning browser automation, Gmail is not the best place to practice. The last time I have checked, it was really tricky to automate.

Comment: I was told to create a complete registration script which involves clicking the verification link to open the further registration steps.

Comment: And i cannot go further with other steps till i click on the verification link from email account.

Comment: @user1177636 and Željko are right.  Gmail is difficult to automate.  A site like [mailinator](http://www.mailinator.com) might do the trick.

Comment: @MaulikGoswami: You were told to do that from UI or from API? If from UI, use Watir, but it's better not doing that, just tell you manager, this is not the correct way of doing things. If from API, you need read gmail gem's documentation and no need to involve Watir here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust your script to find and read the verification email. The following can be used read an email. Depending on the complexity of the email and the contents of your inbox, you may need to make some adjustments.

```
verification_link = ''
Gmail.new("sample@registration.com", "111111") do |gmail|
    #Get the email the first email that is:
    #  unread and 
    #  from 'noreply@registration.com'
    email = gmail.inbox.emails(:unread, :from => 'noreply@registration.com').first

    #Get the message body, which will be in html
    message = email.body.decoded

    #Parse the message body for the link
    #  You may need to adjust the regex depending on the complexity of the email
    #  If the email is very complex, use Nokogiri to parse the html 
    verification_link = /<a.*?href="(.+?)".*?>Verify Now<\/a>/m.match(message)[1].gsub(/\s/, '')
    #=> "http://innovify.in/kwexcui/index.php?r=site/registerFirstSlap/key/3f21f205d603ce83e4dbd4667ff66a1f:2a/id/MTI2ODg2NjM4NTUyNw/lng/eng/email/maulik.goswami@bypeopletechnologies.in/companyName/R09PR0xFIFVLIExJTUlURUQ=/phoneNumber/012345678901234"
end
```

You will not be able to 'click' the link. However, it should be the same as navigating to it in the browser - ie have watir go to the link extracted from the email.

```
br = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
br.goto verification_link
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, this is what i was exactly looking for. But i get some error that URL is invalid. I think it doesn't fetch the exact URL, so how can it be done? I've tried inserting a website URL so it can fetch the exact URL but it didn't work **/"http:\/\/sample.com\/example\/test.php.*?"/**

Comment: Did you try outputting the value of `verification_link` to see if it was the correct URL? The parsing for the link is very specific to the contents of the message - ie you need to provide an example message (ie the value of `email.body.decoded`) if you want an exact answer on how to parse it.

Comment: I tried printing the value of URL but it returns me the blank value. Thanks.

Comment: That means the regex is not finding a match. You need to share the output of `email.body.decoded`, if you want help with the parsing.

Comment: But there are too many lines in it should i share it here only ??

Comment: The more you share, the more help you can get. If it is that large, you could create/share a gist - https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance, here is the link [Verification Mail](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3ab6ec414a905b905ebc)

Comment: Try the updated code for the `verification_link`. Given the sample email, the updated code pulls the href for the Verify Now link.